# We have just read a single numeric digit from the keyboard using the GETC command. Convert this value to binary and place it into R4

Tags: lc3

I need to write this in LC-3 assembly language:

We have just read a single numeric digit from the keyboard using the GETC command. Convert this value to binary and place it into R4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, adapted from a lab manual written by George M. Georgiou and Brian Strader.

> #### 3.2.3 How to read an input value
>
> The assembly command `GETC`, which is another name for `TRAP x20`, reads a single character from the keyboard and places its ASCII value in register R0. The 8 most significant bits of R0 are cleared. There is no echo of the read character. For example, one may use the following code to read a single numerical character, 0 through 9, and place its value in register R3:
>
> ```
> GETC               ; Place ASCII value of input character into R0
> ADD R3, R0, x0     ; Copy R0 into R3
> ADD R3, R3, #−16   ; Subtract 48, the ASCII value of 0
> ADD R3, R3, #−16
> ADD R3, R3, #−16   ; R3 now contains the actual value
> ```
>
> Notice that it was necessary to use three instructions to subtract 48, since the maximum possible value of the immediate operand of `ADD` is 5 bits, in two’s complement format. Thus, -16 is the most we can subtract with the immediate version of the `ADD` instruction. As an example, if the pressed key was "5", its ASCII value 53 will be placed in R0. Subtracting 48 from 53, the value 5 results, as expected, and is placed in register R3.

[Original Source](http://people.cs.georgetown.edu/%7Esquier/Teaching/HardwareFundamentals/LC3-trunk/docs/LC3-AssemblyManualAndExamples.pdf).

You'll need to adapt this to put the result in R4.